# Apache KeepAlive and KeepAliveTimeout

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

Is this a true statement?

If KeepAlive is set to off, it doesn't matter what KeepAliveTimeout is defined to be because KeepAlive is off.

So I'm just confirming I understand this correctly. KeepAliveTimeout bares no relevance when KeepAlive is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct - with `KeepAlive` off, connections will be closed immediately after the request is served, which means that the `KeepAliveTimeout` setting on how long to keep connections open for new requests is irrelevant.

As an aside, for the vast majority of web server workloads, allowing HTTP keepalive is a very good thing from a performance perspective for both the client and the server - turn it off with caution.